# CSS FlexBox - Positioning divs in one container in different places

Tags: html, css

So I have a background image and want to have the Navbar at the top of the screen overlaying the image and the frontInfo div to be in the middle of the screen. But I can't figure out how to position one in the middle and one at the top. I know the basics but I just started learning html and css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title>FlexBox test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="showcase">

        <div class="navBar">
            <h1>NavBar</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Button 1</li>
                <li>Button 2</li>
                <li>Button 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="frontInfo">
            <h1>Learning FlexBox</h1>
            <p>Learn now</p>
            <a href="#" type="button">Read more</a>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>


*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif,"Helvetica Neue";
}

header {
    background-image: url("../img/bg-Image.jpg");

    height: 100vh;

    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#showcase {
    display: flex;
}

#showcase .navBar {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

#showcase .frontInfo {
    flex-direction: column;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply the flex value in your classes before using the flex properties. Like you did for your showcase id, you have to repeat the display flex in each container before applying the flex properties.
Here a funny game : https://flexboxfroggy.com/#fr ^^

For a fixed element look for the 'position' property and its values 'relative', 'fixed', 'absolute'.

Comment: Thank you, love the game too!

Answer (score 0):

You have a flex container element named `#showcase` with two flex elements: `.navBar` and `.frontInfo`. Only the children of an element with the `display: flex` are governed by it. If you have nested flex grids you need to declare the child of the flex container above it as a flex container itself by assigning a `display` of `flex` to it.

Once you have the flex boxes laid out, you need to add container properties to the container elements. For instance, `flex-direction` will orient `.navBar` and `.frontInfo`. The default is 'row' so that is why the elements are in the same row. Set it to 'column' for them to render vertically.

This is a good resource for flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/